# Would allowing user input to python's __import__ be a security risk?

Tags: python, security

Say I create a simple web server using Flask, and allowing people to query certain things that I modulated in different python files, using the `__import__` statement, would doing this with user supplied information be considered a security risk?

Example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<author>/<book>/<chapter>")
def index(author, book, chapter):
    return getattr(__import__(author), book)(chapter)  
    # OR
    return getattr(__import__("books." + author), book)(chapter)
```

I've seen a case like this recently when reviewing code, however it didn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely insecure, and your system is wide open to attack. Your first `return` line doesn't limit what kind of names can be imported, which means the user can execute any arbitrary callable in any importable Python module.

That includes:

```
/pickle/loads/<url-encoded pickle data>
```

A pickle is a stack language that [lets you execute arbitrary Python code](http://www.zopatista.com/plone/2007/11/09/one-cookie-please/), and the attacker can take full control of your server.

Even a prefixed `__import__` would be insecure if an attacker can also place a file on your file system in the `PYTHONPATH`; all they need is a `books` directory earlier in the path. They can then use this route to have the file executed in your Flask process, again letting them take full control.

I would not use `__import__` at all here. Just import those modules *at the start* and use a dictionary mapping `author` to the already imported module. You can use `__import__` still to discover those modules on start-up, but you now remove the option to load arbitrary code from the filesystem.

Allowing untrusted data to direct calling arbitrary objects in modules should also be avoided (including `getattr()`). Again, an attacker that has limited access to the system could exploit this path to widen the crack considerably. Always limit the input to a whitelist of possible options (like the modules you loaded at the start, and per module, what objects can actually be called within).

Comment: I'd reckon using `/os/system/<command>` would be even more efficient in achieving code exec

Comment: @Paradoxis: that'll let you create additional processes. But if I take control of your Flask server *first* I can control how much data is logged, and open a separate connection to then start executing separate commands and find a privilege escalation hole in your OS without you being able to trace later on what happened to your machine.

Comment: Now that's evil

Answer (score 0):

More than being a security risk, it is a bad idea e.g. I could easily crash your web app by visiting the url:

```
/sys/exit/anything
```

translating to:

```
...
getattr(__import__('sys'), 'exit')('anything')
```

Don't give the possibility to import/execute just about anything to your users. Restrict the possibilities by using say a dictionary of permissible imports, as @MartijnPieters as clearly pointed out.